# C - 'no match for operator++ in ++month'

Tags: c, enumeration

I have encountered this example from a textbook and decided to test it in my compiler. However, when I ran the program, I got the error 'no match for operator++ in ++month'. Why is this so?

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum months{
    JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC
};

int main()
{
    enum months month;

    const char *monthName[] = {"", "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"};

    for(month = JAN; month <= DEC; ++month){
        printf("%2d%11s\n", month, monthName[month]);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me! See: http://ideone.com/nJ7j6G

Comment: hmmm.... is this a compiling error or a runtime error?

Comment: re. "the problem cannot be reproduced" votes - it can be reproduced by using a C++ compiler!

Answer (score 6):

You tried to compile with a c++ compiler, it wont compile unless you overload `++` operator for your `enum`, it could be the file extension or may be you used a c++ compiler explicitly.

Comment: @lcm when an answer worked for you, you are free to accept it by clicking the check mark below the votes. I suspect that you don't know that. Do you?